# AWS EC2 CodeDeploy doesn't load javascript from Angular dist folder

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I'm using Bitbucket Pipelines + AWS CodeDeploy + AWS EC2 instance to run my angular app. The pipeline goes well, the code is build on-fly and then for the EC2 it only uploads the dist/ folder. Then when i try access my page, css file and js files are not loaded.

I tried to use another solutions from stackoverflow but nothing worked. The EC2 is running on apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried to grant permissions to execute for the js files but it doesn't work too.

All of the files are in the same directory.

```
/deployment-id/deploment-archive/
-index.html
-runtime.js
-main.js
-polyfills.js
-runtime.js
-styles.css
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="es2015-polyfillsbda95d5896422d031328.js" nomodule></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills8bbb231b43165d65d357.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="maindcabcbb8258040c4d925.js"></script>
```

For now it render only blank page with and i got warnings in console "loading failed for the  with source www.myawslink.com/main.js"

When i try to access the files directly, apache said "404 files not found", but when i connect to ec2 by putty i see the files in the deployment directory with index.html. I want the page to render properly and js files to work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was with apache2.

Because the files are served from /var/www/html/ and in my appspec.yml i included only index.html here

so i changed from this

```
  - source: /index.html
    destination: /var/www/html/
```

to this

```
  - source: /dist
    destination: /var/www/html/
```

And now everything is working perfectly.

and my bitbucket-pipeline.yml look like this

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: build angular
        image: node:10
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm install -g @angular/cli
          - ng build --prod
        artifacts:
          - dist/**
    - step:
        name: deploy
        image: python:3.5.1
        script:
          - apt-get update # required to install zip
          - apt-get install -y zip # required for packaging up the application
          - pip install boto3==1.3.0 # required for codedeploy_deploy.py
          - zip -r /tmp/artifact.zip dist/* scripts/* appspec.yml package.json # package up the application for deployment
          - python codedeploy_deploy.py # run the deployment script
```